# "Succeeding" as the antonym of "Preceding"

Tags: adjectives, word-order, antonyms

If "succeeding" is the antonyms of "preceding", and they are both adjectives, then can I use "succeeding" as in the following examples:

> 1- The **succeeding** word of the adjective is a noun.
>
> 2- The preceding sentence of the subordinate conjunction is an independent sentence, but its **succeeding** one is a dependent sentence.

***?***

And, can it come after the noun in its adjective form?

> The word **succeeding** the adjective is a noun.

If that is a correct ordering of the sentence, then why is it correct? Isn't "succeeding" an adjective that should precede its noun in order to describe it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wold not use "succeeding" in these cases, as it may be (temporarily) ambiguous for the reader / listener. It is very related to "success" also.

A better word without ambiguity is "following", eventually "next" or "after" - depending on the sentence's structure.

Examples 1 and 2 are quite strange for me, even ignoring the ambiguity I just mentioned. he last example sounds very good.

Other ways to express the same thing:

> The word **after** the adjective is a noun.
>
> The **next** word **after** the adjective is a noun.
>
> The first word is an adjective, and the **next** is a noun.
>
> The word **following** the adjective is a noun.

Comment: Thank you, virolino. Very well-stated suggestions! As you have suggested "following", can it be substituted with "succeeding" in the examples I've provided?

Comment: I added to the answer. I hope I understood your question right.